# C++, using if/else to return values in struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm learning "struct" and I don't understand why it is not returning values from struct based on conditions. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Student{
    char name[15];
    unsigned char mark;
};

struct Group{
    Student *students;
    size_t size;
};

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 2;

    std::cout << "Student(s) we have: " << std::endl;

    Group group;
    group.size = N;
    group.students = new Student[N];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        Student &input = group.students[i];
        std::cout << "Student #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> input.name;
        std::cout << "Score: ";
        std::cin >> input.mark;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        const Student &dummys = group.students[i];
        if(dummys.mark == 5) std::cout << dummys.name << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] group.students;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to return a student who's score is '5' (I should enter student's name and mark). When I do - my code returns nothing...

Comment: replace `if(dummys.mark == 5)` with `if(dummys.mark == '5')` and try again

Comment: or replace char with int in declaration of Student struct[for the variable mark !!]

Comment: Off-topic:  Use `std::string` for text, not character arrays.  The `std::string` type can grow dynamically, whereas character arrays have a fixed capacity and can overflow easily.

Answer (score 2):

You store the mark in `unsigned char`, so when you use 
        `std::cin >> input.mark;` and type '5' the value typed is not parsed into integer type and is saved as indeed '5' - character with integer value 53 (from ASCII table). 
You can use `dummys.mark == '5'` comparision and get your code working.